# Open sets under equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Find all open sets of X, where X is the quotient space of $\mathbb{R}$ recieved from the following equivalence relation:

$$x \sim y \iff \exists n\in \mathbb{Z} : n<x,y\leq n+1$$

Is it true that all the open sets of X are from the form $I_n = (n, \infty)$? ( and obviously the empty set and the space X itself )

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser Hi, thank you for this comment. Just edited my question, hope its better :)

Comment: A good first step might be figuring out what the equivalence classes look like (and adding what you figured out about that to the question).

Comment: And after thinking about it a bit, I'll also suggest that you rewrite the condition to $\exists n \in \mathbb Z : n-1\lt x,y \le n$. It's clearly equivalent, but I think it'll make it easier to talk about what happens when discussing $[x]$ when $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Responding to your suggestion that we consider the set $(n, n+1)$, remember that we can project that down, but then we have to pull it back, and that pull back must be open in R. Since our quotient map is very much not injective, the pull back is going to be bigger than the original set.

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike Thank you for your help. just edited, think it might be true now.